# How can I read from localStorage and mutate state in Vue store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have property that I set in `localStorage`, `enableLog = false`. If I write in the console `localStorage.enableLog = true`, How can I read that value in my vuex store and flip my state from `false` to `true` and trigger a `console.log`?

What I'm trying to do is add ad-hoc console logging. For example, we have an app that will send data to another app, that is launched in a pop up window. In the pop up app, if another dev changes `enableLog` from `false` to `true`, he/she will be able to see that initial data in the payload sent to the pop up app via a function that `console.logs`. How can my app read the `localStorage` property, how then do I update state from that, and lastly where does the re-render to trigger the function to call that `console.log` go?

`index.js`, state:

```
isLoggingData: false
```

`index.js`, actions:

```
async init ({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await messaging.send(ACTION.READY)
      commit(types.SET_LOGGING_DATA, data) // capture this initial data to be used later
```

`index.js` mutations:

```
  [types.SET_LOGGING_DATA] (state, isLoggingData) {
    state.loggedData.initData = isLoggingData
  },
```

`App.vue`:

```
async created () {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggingData', this.isLoggingData)
    await this.onCreated()

async onCreated () {
      await this.init()
```

I don't know how to listen to the change in `localStorage.isLoggingData`.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example so it will easy to other people for problem hunting.

Answer (score 0):

[`vuex-shared-mutations`](https://github.com/xanf/vuex-shared-mutations) should fit your needs.

```
Share vuex mutations across tabs via `localStorage`.
```